# List all “.csv” filename and then enter corresponding the code to plot the graph

Tags: python

There is a folder which contains lot of data for example the folder contains ".html" files , ".jpeg" files, ".pdf"files, ".csv" files(There are plenty of ".csv" excel sheets in the folder containing different file names). Here is the code which list only csv files.

```
import os
path = "F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary"
files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.csv' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
            test_folders = os.listdir(path) 
for f in files:
    print(f)
file_code = int(input("Enter Corresponding code to plot: "))
```

When i run the above code i get output as:

```
F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary\Test_Summary_1.csv 
F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary\Test_Summary_2.csv
F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary\Test_Summary_3.csv
```

Actually i want Output to be displayed as:

```
0-Test_Summary_1.csv
1-Test_Summary_2.csv
2-Test_Summary_3.csv
3-Test_Summary_4.csv
4-Test_Summary_5.csv
5-Test_Summary_6.csv etc
```

How do i modify it to get as said above?? i will later use that code num to plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip joining the paths.

```py
import os
path = "F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary"
files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.csv' in file:
            files.append(file)
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    print("%d-%s"%( i,f))
    csv_code = int(input("Enter corresponding code to plot: "))
    csv_path = os.path.join(path, files[csv_code])

    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=None)
    #df1 = df[0:2]
    df1 = df.iloc[:,0:2]
    plt.plot(df1[0], df1[1])
```

Comment: the output is displaying only 1 excel file after modifing it

Comment: i want all csv excel sheets to be displayed from that folder

Comment: its saying invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly appended `)` inside code. Now I've removed it…

Comment: i mean when i enter that code it should plot the graph

Comment: csv_code = int(input("Enter corresponding code to plot: "))
    csv_path = folder_name_path + "\\" + folder_name_data[csv_code]
    
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=None)
    #df1 = df[0:2]
    df1 = (df.iloc[:,0:2])
    plt.plot(df1[0], df1[1])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194004/discussion-between-priyanka-mishra-and-mitiku).